# React Native navigationOptions

Tags: react-native

How can I make  navigationOptions visibility to false. I have the following code on my page:

```
class MainActivity extends Component {


  static navigationOptions = {
    title: 'Welcome',
  };
```

I don't want welcome to be displayed. I don't want even the top part to be showing up on my phone. Below is the image if my phone:

[image]

where the red arrow is pointing, I don't want that top portion to be displayed. How can I make the navigationOption invisible.

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: `headerMode:'none'` ?

Comment: Did you read the documentation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to pass **navigationOptions** in **StackNavigator** in your application.:

```
 MainActivity: {
    screen: MainActivity,
    navigationOptions: {
      header: null,
    }
  },
```

You can get more information about navigationOptions from [this link](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/stack-navigator.html).

Answer (score 1):

This option done your job

```
class MainActivity extends Component   {
    static navigationOptions = { 
         header: null 
     };
```

Answer (score 0):

`static navigationOptions = {
    header: null,

}`

Comment: This snippet is already present in the existing answers... No need to repeat it again.